# Calculation of definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If someone could please help me with this question, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

I have the following definite integral

$$\int_0^9 {\sqrt {{({2x-6})^2}+{({2x-6})^2}}} \,dx \\$$

$$\int_0^9 { \sqrt {{2({2x-6})^2}}} \,dx \\$$

$$\int_0^9 { \sqrt {{2}}({2x-6})} \,dx \\$$

$$ \sqrt {{2}} \int_0^9 { ({2x-6})} \,dx \\$$

So after integrating, I obtain the following: (I checked this with online integral calculators as well)

$$\ {\sqrt{2} } (x^2-6x)\, \\$$

So if I am evaluating this integral from 0 to 9, would my answer not be $$\ {27\sqrt{2} }\, \\$$

I don't know why the answer is

$$\ {45\sqrt{2} }\, \\$$

Anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: @RonGordon   I'm not sure how the absolute sign would change it? Does having an absolute sign around $$\ (2x-6)\, \\$$ in my integral above change the value of 27 I get?

Comment: hint:  the sqrt function is always positive,  in your method, is your integrand always positive throughout the whole interval [0,9] ?

Comment: @dm63  Ah yes, I see what you mean, I split my integral into two parts, from 0 to 3 and from 3 to 9 and obtained the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the absolute value.
$$\sqrt{2}\int_0^9|2x-6|dx=\sqrt{2}\left(\int_0^3(6-2x)dx+\int_3^9(2x-6)dx\right)$$
which is equal to $$\sqrt{2}\left(6x-x^2|_0^3+x^2-6x|_3^9\right)=45\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the radicand and find where it's negative.

$$2x-6<0$$

$$x<3$$

Thus, your third step becomes this:

$$-\sqrt 2\int_0^3(2x-6)dx+\sqrt2\int_3^9(2x-6)dx$$

$$-\sqrt2(x^2-6x)_0^3+\sqrt2(x^2-6x)_3^9$$

$$=9\sqrt2+27\sqrt2-(-9\sqrt2)$$

$$=45\sqrt2$$